# Issue with saving contents of the uploaded text file in the database field

Tags: php, codeigniter

//my model test.php is as follows

```
public function saveallpars($id)
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = sys_get_temp_dir();
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'txt';
        $config['xss_clean']        = false;
        $config['overwrite']        = true;
             $config['return_temp_file'] = true;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$file =  $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            dd($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $contents = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
            $this->data= serialize($contents);
            $this->db->where(array('id' => $id))->set(array('data' =>$this->data))->update($this->_table);

        }
```

I am trying to save the contents of the text file in the data base field "data". But it is not saved. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have u tried so far? and how (structure) u want to save it

Comment: Have you checked the codeignitor documentaion? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/index.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/queries.html should get you started...

Comment: if you have already uploaded file on server... why need to save whole text of file instead of just file path...

Comment: this is not how you get the file path `$file = $this->upload->do_upload();` ... read the docs